# Prove that $\sum_{n}\frac{a_n}{n^\beta}$ converges given convergence of $\sum_{n}\frac{a_n}{n^\alpha}$ for $\alpha<\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^\alpha} $converges, for any $\beta>\alpha$, prove that  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n^\beta} $ also converges.

I suppose that it can be proved with Cauchy convergence theorem, but I failed.
Also, I have no idea how to deal with For any $\beta>\alpha$,should I compare them with zero? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is nothing known about $a_n$ ? It would be nicer if the $a_i$ were positive.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM  It's not sure whether $a_i$ is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Abel Discriminance to this problem.

Comment: Yes,I  get it.Thanks.

Comment: What is the Abel Discriminance? I've never heard of this before and a google search yields nothing except a paper behind a paywall.

Comment: Oh, I mean "Abel test" [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test)

Answer (score 7):

Dirichlet test actually does the trick.

Rewrite $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{a_n}{n^\beta}=\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{a_n}{n^\alpha}\times \frac{1}{n^{\beta-\alpha}}$

The partial sums of $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac{a_n}{n^\alpha}$ are bounded by the initial assumption and $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^{\beta-\alpha}}$ is a decreasing sequence that goes to $0$.